# Measuring the velocity of a pendulum using the width of the bob

Tags: kinematics, experimental-technique

I did an experiment on pendulum motion and in the method it says use the following equation to measure the velocity of the pendulum:
$$v=\frac{W}{t}$$
where $W$ is the width of the pendulum bob and t is the time.
Why is this? Is it correct?

Edit: the time is for the bob to cross the photogate.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $W=\Delta x$ and that $t$ is the time required for the bob to pass to lowest position (I presume you have a photogate set up?). So by dividing the width of the bob and the time it takes to cross the sensor, you have the *average* velocity, $v=\Delta x/\Delta t$, at the point of the sensor (presumably at the trough).

I have had students get less than 1% error on their lab using this approximation, so I would say yes it is correct.

Comment: That is exactly right, we have a photogate. My teacher didn't explain the theory for some reason. Thank you!

Comment: @user2357 This hardly qualifies as theory. It's just one step away from done and you should be prepared to understand such things for yourself in the future.

Comment: The thing is that I didn't know what the time was, initially I thought it was the whole oscillation. Yes, you're right, it is just basic stuff.

Comment: That'll do it. An important thing here is not to be afraid to have a go at figuring it out. Guess and see if it makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Typically you see this in a case where the bob occludes light beam or some such.

So what time is it that is measured? There are several options but the likely one here is the length of time during which the beam in blocked.

Now how far does the bob move in that time? Well, it moves from the point where it first blocks the beam to the point when it stops blocking the beam, which is to say the width on the bob in the direction of motion.

If these two things are true than the (average) velocity of the bob while the sensor is blocked is, by definition the distance traveled of the time it takes to travel it, no? More over, if the width of the bob represents a small angular range in the swing you can take this to be the instantaneous veolocity with very little error.

Comment: In the textbook the method used to study pendulum motion is through the use of the equation $T=2\pi \sqrt{\frac{l}{g}}$. It makes sense now that we are finding the velocity using this simple technique.

Comment: Notice that the equation you quoted tells you something about the *whole* swing, while the measurement you are making tells you something about one part of the swing. Different things.